# Comparison of numbers in Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, 32-bit, comparison

How to compare two numbers if they are greater than 32 bit integer in dos in a 32 bit system? The two numbers are the size of folders in bytes. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Are you referring to `MS-DOS` or the command line interpreter that comes with Windows XP/Vista/7?

Comment: cammand line interpreter

Comment: @Sachin - The command prompt is a 32-bit process.  This means that an integer is its normal size.

Comment: if `powershell` is an option, it's easiest: it will auto choose either int32 or int64 so this runs fine: `powershell 10000000000 -ge 20000000000000`

Comment: **I went ahead and remove the ms-dos tag since it clearly indicates NOT to use it for command prompt questions.**

Comment: @techie007 Ya I tried this one but it throws error like Numbers are  limited to 32 bits of precision

Answer (score 1):

The idea of techie007 is actually usable *when using padded strings* instead of numbers:

```
set num1=666123456789
set num2=123450123456789
set "tmp1=               %num1%"
set "tmp2=               %num2%"
set pad1="%tmp1:~-15%"
set pad2="%tmp2:~-15%"
if %pad1% gtr %pad2% …
```

In this code you can compare 2 numbers with up to 15 digits:

- `numX` hold the number strings
- `tmpX` hold the number strings prefixed with 15 spaces
- `padX` hold the last 15 characters in quotes —> padded number strings, now ready for comparison!

Better put this in a subroutine if you need to compare more numbers, or if applicable, sort the padded strings via the available `sort` command.